# How can I add custom headers before publishing message in Masstransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

I am trying to add extra headers in the message before publishing the message to a Queue.
I am unable to add UseSendFilter() and UseConsumeFilter() while creating the bus control
Please find the message payload and the bus configuration below.
Please note the target framework is dotnet v4.8

Payload:

```
using System;
using MassTransit;

namespace Payload
{
    public interface IPublishMessage : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        string Sender { get; set; }
        QueueType QueueType { get; set; }
        MessageType MessageType { get; set; }
        ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
        string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Publisher :

```
 var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(busFactoryConfigurator =>
            {
                busFactoryConfigurator.Host(new Uri(Config.ConnectionString), host =>
                {
                    host.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan;
                    //TODO Add Token Provider
                });

                busFactoryConfigurator.UseSendContext()

                busFactoryConfigurator.SendTopology.UseCorrelationId<IPublishMessage>(x => x.CorrelationId);
                // TODO Add Headers from IPublishMessage
                // TODO Refer https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/scoped.html

                busFactoryConfigurator.Message<IPublishMessage>(topologyConfigurator =>
                {
                    topologyConfigurator.SetEntityName(Config.TopicExchange);
                });
            });

            await busControl.StartAsync(CancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await busControl.Publish(message.Content, CancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await busControl.StopAsync(CancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

I would like to add the below properties from the payload to the header:

```
string Name { get; set; }
        DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        string Sender { get; set; }
        QueueType QueueType { get; set; }
        MessageType MessageType { get; set; }
        ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding headers when publishing/sending a message is [covered in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#send-headers).

In your example:

```csharp
await busControl.Publish(message.Content, context =>
{
    context.Headers.Set("QueueType", message.QueueType.ToString());
    context.Headers.Set("MessageType", message.MessageType.ToString());
    // etc.
    
}, CancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I didnt notice that.